# Remove hash when i click in the jumplink of the menu

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a menu, and i dont really know why, but when i click into a section, the url changes and some css animations break, it also takes me to another page (i gess, because the url changes and after clicking, the # get unto the url THXXX [image]

```
            <li id="ini"><a href="#parte1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Inicio&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this a functioning jump link on the page you can use jQuery to prevent default so it doesn't reload the page with the hash at the end of the url, then add the referenced id in the href to a section so you navigate directly to it on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ini a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
            <li id="ini"><a href="#parte1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Inicio&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>

</ul>

<div style="height: 500px">
abc
</div>
<div id="parte1">Inicio seccion</div>
```

Comment: This reminds me the meme that said on SO you only see people that advise jQuery for everything ahah btw `preventDefault()` is a method (you need to call it) and it's in vanilla JavaScript

Comment: @CristianTraìna im lost. So... what should i do to make it functional?

Comment: @Izar if you are running jQuery do as I suggested.